# How to make a shared-state object thread safe

Tags: multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr

I am dealing with an class implementing shared-data copy semantics, so that the copy of an object will internally share the same data as the original object.

This class is essentially a wrapper around a `std::shared_ptr` with some convenience accessors. A stripped down version would be:

```
class ControlParameters {

  using ControlsMap = std::map<std::string, float>;

public:
  ControlParameters() : controls_(std::make_shared<ControlsMap>()) {};
  ControlParameters(const ControlParameters& other) = default;
  ControlParameters& operator=(const ControlParameter& other) = default;
  ControlParameters(ChannelControlParameter&& other) = delete;
  ControlParameters& operator=(ControlParameter&& other) = delete;

  void setValue(float value, const std::string& key) const
  {
    auto& currentValue = (*controls_)[key];
    if (currentValue != value)
      currentValue = value;
  };

  float operator[](const std::string& key) const
  {
    return (*controls_)[key];
  };

private:
  std::shared_ptr<ControlsMap> controls_;
};
```

Now I realise the need to make the class thread-safe as well, to ensure atomic read/write. Note that concurrent access in this case should be intended as access from different threads and different instances sharing the same data. How can I go about it?

Note: I am aware of c++17 shared_mutex which could serve my purpose, but I cannot yet use c++17 features.

Comment: The simple answer is: every funtion that accesses/modifies the shared state must be protected by a mutex. If multiple users can read at the same time a semaphor might be more appropriate.

Comment: @RedX But how can you incorporate the internal mutex with the copy semantics of this class? Could it be as simple as using a 'std::shared_ptr<std::mutex>' member?

Comment: That is enough to solve  the problem of using the member funcitons but making the copy thread safe will probably require a static mutex to make the copying safe.

Comment: @RedX Uhmmmm... but if I use a share pointer pointer on the mutex the mutex itself is not copied (std::mutex is not copiable, of course). It now seems to me that thread safety would not be a problem during copy.

Comment: Write a class that wraps your `ControlsMap` and exposes accessors as necessary. That class should carry a mutex, and use it to synchronize its methods. Make `controls_` a `shared_ptr<ThatWrapperClass>`. This way, the synchronization is where it belongs - shared together with the data it protects.